# Force browser to clear cache - gulp-cache-bust

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, browser-cache

I'm very new in frontend development, I need to force the browser to refresh the cache every time I published a new version of the app frontend. Browsing Internet I have seen this gulp plugin, gulp-cache-bust, but I'm not sure how to use it, there is not much information about it. I need it to apply to all .css .js .png files.
I understand that I have to add something like the following to my gulpfile.js, but with this part `.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));` for example I have doubts. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
var cachebust = require('gulp-cache-bust');

gulp.src('./dist/*/*.html')
    .pipe(cachebust({
        type: 'timestamp'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the gulp plugin, but can't you simply develop in incognito mode in the browser to delete the cache?

If you are talking about distributing new files to the user, I would suggest utilizing a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/). Not only does this kill two birds with one stone (way faster running apps, offline capabilities, etc) but you also can notify the user of changes you have made to the dist, and they can manually accept the changes when they are done, or close the browser and the new changes will take place on the next reload.